# Detect if moving points on circle step over each other

Tags: trigonometry

We have a circle and two points ($a$ and $b$) on it described by angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Now we move the points by angles $\Delta_\alpha$ and $\Delta_\beta$ (deltas can be negative and also greater than $2\pi$) so that we get new angles $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_1$ that describe the new, moved points. What we are interested in, is if one point stepped over the other. How to figure it out in most elegant way?

To recapitulate:
Input: $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\Delta_\alpha$, $\Delta_\beta$
Output: $true$ or $false$ ($true$ in case one point stepped over another)

Some example diagrams:
[image: diagram 1]
Here points don't jump over each other.

[image: diagram 2]
Here, instead, point $a$ jumps over point $b$.

I hope this "jumping over" (or stepping over) is clear. The thing is, if $\alpha$ was less than $\beta$ before the movement, then if after the movement $\alpha_1$ is greater than $\beta_1$, the point $a$ jumped over $b$. This is just an example to explain this concept... if it's not clear, do ask.

Comment: Is the second last sentence the definition of "jumping over"? And are the angles always viewed as positive (except for the deltas)?

Comment: Angles are in $[0..2\pi]$ range (although that doesn't matter. You can always make them be in that range). The definition of jumping over (stepping over) would be this: if during the movement the two points coincided at some some point, then they jumped over one another.

You can also imagine two planets on the same circular orbit around a sun, and you move them for $\Delta t$ in time each with his own angular velocity, and then you try to detect if they collided. This is just an example to immagine the problem easier.

Comment: So each move takes the same fixed time for both points? And presumably if a delta is negative the point moves clockwise and otherwise counter-clockwise?

Comment: Yes, exactly so.

Answer (score 1):

After giving it much thought, I think I came up with a robust solution myself. This is the idea:

$\vec{r} = \beta - \alpha$
$\vec{r_1} = (\beta+\Delta_{\beta}) - (\alpha+\Delta_{\alpha}) = \beta_1 - \alpha_1$

`result = r*r1 < 0 || abs(r1) > 2*pi` (in programming notation)

In other words, if signs of $r$ and $r_1$ differ, then there was a collision (a step over), or if $|r_1|>2\pi$ there was a collision as well. This last case is needed because of overlapping (when going over 360 degrees or bellow 0 degrees).

I think this solution covers all cases (if someone can confirm it, I'd be grateful).